# My own variable for long paths

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I'm writing some backup script and target path is pretty long. Could I define something like this?

```
TARGET='/media/user/externaldrive/folder with spaces/blahblah'
```

And then use it like this as part of a path?

```
cp file.txt '$TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt'
```

Variable can be defined for this script only.

What is the right way to do this? Because this is what I get:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘$TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: for system wide use or just this script ? If it is the second options, why don't try it yourself with some small files ;) I've set some variables containing paths in scripts myself and it works just fine

Comment: Oh, sorry.. you have mentioned "this script only"

Comment: Also you've got it pretty much right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable assignment is correct, but you have a syntax mistake in your command that uses the variable:

What you need to type instead is:

```
cp file.txt "${TARGET}/some folder with spaces/file.txt"
```

```
cp file.txt "$TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt"
```

Note the <del>two</del> changes:

- Double quotes `"..."` instead of single quotes `'...'`, because double quotes allow bash variable expansion, while single quotes prohibit that and keep the string as it is.
- <del>As the variable is directly embedded into the path string and no spaces are before and after its name, we need `${variable}` instead of just `$variable` here. The curled braces tell bash where exactly the variable name ends, otherwise this would not be clear.</del>

  The curly braces are not wrong, but also not necessary here in this case, as the next character after the variable name is a `/`, which is not allowed in the name itself and therefore separates the name from the rest of the string.
  *Thanks to **@heemayl**'s answer for correcting this!*

Answer (score 1):

There are certain rules of setting the name of a variable in `bash`:

- Vaiables's name can only contain characters from `[[:alnum:]_]` i.e. `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`.
- Variable's name can not start with a digit

So while getting the value of the variable, unless you have any of these characters following the variable you don't need `{}` to wrap the variable's name:

```
$ 1foo=bar
1foo=bar: command not found

$ foo1=bar

$ echo "$foo1"
bar

$ echo "$foo12"

$ echo "${foo1}2"
bar2

$ echo "$foo1_"

$ echo "${foo1}_"
bar_
```

In your case:

- Remove the single quotes and put double quotes while using `cp`, everything inside a single quote is taken literally so the variable will not be expanded
- Double quote is necessary because you have spaces in file path, so if you don't use quotes it will suffer from word splitting while using `cp`
- While getting the value, `$TARGET` is followed by `/` which is not a valid variable name constituent character so `{}` is not neccessary

  ```
  $ TARGET='/media/user/externaldrive/folder with spaces/blahblah'

  $ echo '$TARGET' 
  $TARGET

  $ echo '$TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt'
  $TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt

  $ echo "$TARGET/some folder with spaces/file.txt"
  /media/user/externaldrive/folder with spaces/blahblah/some folder with spaces/file.txt
  ```

Comment: You're right! Upvoted your and edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: YES!  You got it 100% correct.  Although, if you want to make that variable available to other scripts, don't forget to run `export TARGET`.

Comment: Well, I must be doing something wrong because I always get: cp: cannot create regular file ‘$TARGET/some folder/’: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running `mkdir '$TARGET/blah/'`?

Comment: Sorry, but a plain YES in this case is just wrong. -1